# JS - How to find specific element TAG from a button click event to remove it?

Tags: javascript, html

If a button in my HTML is clicked, it should search / find the next parent 'table' element and delete it completly. How can I do that? Please check JS to find out what I have already test it.

**My HTML:**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">            
    <!-- OTHER HTML CODE with div etc. DONT REMOVE/TOUCH THIS! -->
</table>


 <table class="table table-bordered"> <!-- THIS table element should delete, if the button is clicked -->
    <hr class="my-4 border-dark" id="hereWeGo">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto justify-content-around d-flex flex-column border">
        <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger" id="RemoveBtn">Remove</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col border">
        <B>Title...</B><br />
        <hr class="my-1">
        Link...
      </div>
    </div>
  </table>



 <table class="table table-bordered">            
    <!-- OTHER HTML CODE with div etc. DONT REMOVE/TOUCH THIS! -->
</table>
```

**My JS:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
//$(this).parents('table').remove();
//alert("im here");
//$(this).parents('table').remove();
//alert($(this).parents('hr').html()); 
//$('div.row').remove();

// after this is run, it should remove the <table class="table table-bordered"> element....

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest("table").remove();
```

However, your HTML is not valid: `table` cannot have `div` or `hr` tags as direct children, and so the `table` is not really the parent of the button. Browsers "fix" the error, and move all those invalid child elements out of the `table`.

This solution will only work if you make your `table` structure valid HTML. So, no children of it should be `div`.

For instance:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest("table").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr class="my-4 border-dark" id="hereWeGo">
<table class="table table-bordered"> <!-- THIS table element should delete, if the button is clicked -->
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-auto justify-content-around d-flex flex-column border">
        <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger" id="RemoveBtn">Remove</button>
      </td>
      <td class="col border">
        <B>Title...</B><br />
        <hr class="my-1">
        Link...
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OK I see... Thanks a lot for the hint, regarding the HTML is not valid. I just add the table tag, to find a parent. Would this be a valid HTML if I would replace the table tag with DIV - only to achieve the removement by closet("divClass")

Comment: Sure that will work. Note the spelling `closest`, and if you reference a class, don't forget the dot: `closest(".divClass")`.

Comment: OK thanks, but is there a difference of syntax for CLASS or DIV ID? I mean its always the value like here: `closest("class name or DIV ID")`. Reason why I am asking is, somethimes there are multiple classes. I never know, if i have to put one class name or all other example:  `class="remove btn btn-danger"`

Comment: And why `<hr class="my-4 border-dark" id="hereWeGo">` cannot be a part of the TABLE? :(

Comment: To target an element you just need something that is precise enough to identify it. So usually one of the classes is enough: `closest(".remove")` or `.closest(".btn")` or `.closest(".btn-danger")` would all work, but if you have more elements with the same class, you will want to select by the class that is most unique. To select by ID, you need a hash: `closest("#someid")`. As ID values must be unique in valid HTML, such a selector is always good enough.

Comment: A `table` element cannot have a `hr` element as direct child. You can however put it inside a `<tr><td>`. But if you would make the parent a `div` instead of a `table`, then it can be a direct child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185754/discussion-between-emba-bakar-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the JQuery `closest()` function.